# The ascx code is Not calling its webMethod why but when i use it in normal aspx page it works fine

Tags: asp.net

My code is not working but when i use it with normal asp page it works fine.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCity(string prefixText, string contextKey)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERPConnection"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        string CmdText = "select name+ '-' + ' ['+CONVERT(VARCHAR, custid) +']'as name from ht_cust where name like @City+'%' and EmpID =@EmpId";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdText, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", prefixText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", contextKey);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        List<string> CityNames = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CityNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
    return CityNames;
    }
```

ascx code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" UseContextKey="true" onkeyup="SetContextKey()"
            CssClass="input-1" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxtoolkit:autocompleteextender id="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtCity"
            minimumprefixlength="1" enablecaching="true" completionsetcount="1" completioninterval="1000"
            servicemethod="GetCity" usecontextkey="true" completionlistcssclass="autocomplete_completionListElement">
                                                        </ajaxtoolkit:autocompleteextender>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145841/the-ascx-code-is-not-calling-its-webmethod-why-but-when-i-use-it-in-normal-aspx) for details on why you can't call `web method` defined in `ascx user controls`

Comment: Can any body help me out?

Comment: why do you want web method "in a user control"?

Comment: deostroll i am using a web method to autocomplete a textbox from database

Comment: i has become a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

i hopoe you have added attribute EnablePageMethods = "true"  to your scriptmanager on page 
and add attribute UpdateMode="Conditional" to your updatepanel

Comment: ok i have tried this but my scriptmanager is at master page,so it will work in this case.

Comment: then try adding ScriptManagerProxy on you ascx and then try above solution

Comment: sir can you please explain how to add ScriptManagerProxy .?

Comment: [Try this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-an-aspnet-ajax-scriptmanagerproxy)

Comment: are you getting some kind of error in code or in FireBug on request